# Utilizing browser back/forward buttons in a vue.js app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state

I have an app that has a bunch of dropdown components that alter state.  .  The state of the dropdowns control a main datatable that has info based around the params.  Cool.

I want to also alter the URL so users can share urls with their coworkers and simply have the datatable show up without choosing dropdown parameters.

Example: http://localhost:8080/?region=372&pc=341&pc=375 or http://localhost:8080/?region=372&pc=341&vendor=123456

Right now I've got this working by manually watching the dropdown parameters selected (via `watch`) and building a url and using `this.$router.push` to update browser history when things change.  I have a feeling this isn't totally correct, but it's the only reliable way I've been able to make the url update consistently.

The main issue is that when I hit the browser's back/forward buttons, the components do not update their state based on the url.  The application remains in it's current state if I hit back/forward.  How do I properly go about this?

Comment: Are you using history mode?

Comment: Yes.  No hasbangs.

Comment: I'd guess it's because you're using URL query parameters, which don't bind like vue-router's route parameters. Maybe you can put a watcher on `$route.query` and set data based on the changed value?

Comment: This is what I am doing right now, but the issue is that it seems like a lot of manual work for something that I thought the framework would have a way to deal with a bit more easily.  The main issue is that I alter the url query when a user alters the state, which in turn re-populates the datatable.  
 When the url query updates based on the the above, watching `$route.query` update the state of the app based on the URL.  This kinda results in a circlular-population issue.  I had to manually set a variable when the state was manually updated so as not to re-check `$route.query`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're effectively trying to bind the state of your dropdown to your URL query. VueRouter, unfortunately, doesn't have a baked-in solution for this.

I'm not sure how your data is structured, so let's assume you have an object `dropdownParams` containing the relevant parameters:

```
dropdownParams: {
  region: 372,
  pc: 341,
  vendor: 123456,
}
```

You need to set a watcher on `dropdownParams` to update the query in the `$route` when those are updated. Use `$router.replace` instead of `$router.push` so that the history doesn't change:

```
watch: {
  dropdownParams(params) {
    // format the data however you want this is an example with lodash
    let query = _.pickBy(params, p => !_.isEmpty(p));
    this.$router.replace({ query: query });
  }
}
```

Then, in the `mounted` hook, you can set the `dropdownParams` object based on any relevant `$route.query` parameters, if they already exist:

```
mounted() {
  let keys = _.keys(this.dropdownParams);
  _.assign(this.dropdownParams, _.pick(this.$route.query, keys));
}
```

Now, when the user changes the dropdown parameters, those changes will be reflected in the URL. And, if the user loads the component with URL query parameters already present, the component will set those values to the dropdown.

Comment: Does the mounted hook also work for browser back/forward buttons if the same component is being used for the routes in question?

Comment: `mounted` will fire once when the component is mounted to the DOM. If the component hangs around when the route changes, it won't fire.

Comment: So once again, we're back to how to handle browser back/forward usage.  Seems like it needs to manually be done.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If the route changes to include the component with the dropdown, the `mounted` function will fire, updating the `dropdownParams`. Or do you mean you want to hit the back button after adding a param and it removes the param instead of going to the previous route?

Comment: If I add a query param to the url, it's technically the same route, yes?  Because of that, I have to watch `$route.query`.  Because if I click the back button, the same route is accessed, therefore unless I manually update the state nothing will happen.

I apologize if this is confusing.  I'm not entirely sure how to show the issue given the component.  I'll try to break it down a bit and give a bear-bones example.

Comment: Correct, adding a param to the url doesn't change the route. If you're saying  that, when you hit the back button, you want to stay on the route but remove the query param, then you will have to watch `$route.query` as well. And in that case, you would want to use `$router.push` instead of `$router.replace`. Is that your desired behavior?

Comment: The desired behaviour is to update the URL yes, but the browser takes care of that.  The next step is to watch `$route.query` and update the state based on the updated query params.  Since the route, hence the state is not updated, I have to manually track this.  I've got everything working, but it was a lot of manual intervention to make it function.